# R: divide every entry of the matrix if it's larger then zero

Tags: r

I need to divide 1 by every entry in the matrix if the entry is larger then zero. I currently use the following (1. divide. 2. convert Inf to zero), but it work very slowly, and the matrix is huge.

```
wii <- 1/wii
wii[is.infinite(wii)] <- 0
```

Can you please suggest how to optimize that? I think that applying the function for every entry with mapply should work, but I don't know how to use condition in that case.
Thank you for suggestions!

```
# example

0   0   0   0   1000
0   100 0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   10  0
0   0   0   0   0
1   0   10  0   0
0   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your order is the problem. Why do division on elements that you're going to be converting to zero anyway?

```
wii[wii!=0] <- 1/wii[wii!=0]
```

**EDIT**

The issue was that `wii` was a `data.frame` and not a `matrix`. Matrix operations are way faster, and indexing `df[df==...]` obviously won't work.

The above solution will only improve performance if the actual operations on the matrix take too much time - in this case they don't.

Comment: -1; this is slower in a simple test for `wii = matrix(sample(c(0,10), 1e6, T), nrow = 1e3)`, so I'd like to see proof this adds anything of value

Comment: yep, that's actually also slow

Comment: How big is your matrix?

Comment: 8000 by 3000, most of entries are zero (95%)

Comment: It takes about 1 second on my machine. Is that too long for `2.4e7` operations?

Comment: My fault! the dataframe wasn't a matrix

Answer (score 3):

This will be a bit faster:

```
wii <- 1/(1/(1-1/(wii == 0)) + wii)
```

Even better though (and simpler!) is the @sgibb version in the comments (and it'll be even better for mostly 0 matrices):

```
tmp <- which(wii != 0)
wii[tmp] <- 1/wii[tmp];
```

Benchmarks:

```
N = 1e3

wii = matrix(sample(c(0, 10), N*N, T), nrow = N)

op = function(wii) {
  wii <- 1/wii
  wii[is.infinite(wii)] <- 0
}

so = function(wii) {
  tmp <- wii != 0     # doing this is faster than Señor O's original answer
  wii[tmp] <- 1/wii[tmp]
}

ed = function(wii) {
  wii <- 1/(1/(1-1/(wii == 0)) + wii)
}

sg = function(wii) {
  tmp <- which(wii != 0)
  wii[tmp] <- 1/wii[tmp];
}

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(op(wii), so(wii), ed(wii), sg(wii), times = 100)
#Unit: milliseconds
#    expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
# op(wii) 47.91634  64.51116  76.39793  88.13995 125.72246   100
# so(wii) 82.00116 114.90850 133.25893 150.97547 196.63302   100
# ed(wii) 26.80661  41.64416  66.26577  79.08794 130.08377   100
# sg(wii) 30.86709  43.68241  50.01369  61.89294  97.65006   100
```

Comment: IMHO `so = function(wii) { tmp <- which(wii != 0); wii[tmp] <- 1/wii[tmp]; }` will beat all given alternative approaches. Especially if 95% of the matrix are zero.